# How to calculate pairwise cosine similarity score for every row in a data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, apply, cosine-similarity

I have a DF as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"q1":['What is the step by step guide to invest in share market in india?',
                                'What is the story of Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) Diamond?',
                                'How can I increase the speed of my internet connection while using a VPN?',
                                'Why am I mentally very lonely? How can I solve it?',
                                'Which one dissolve in water quikly sugar, salt, methane and carbon di oxide?'],
                          "q2":['What is the step by step guide to invest in share market?',
                                'What would happen if the Indian government stole the Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) diamond back?',
                                'How can Internet speed be increased by hacking through DNS?',
                                'Find the remainder when [math]23^{24}[/math] is divided by 24,23?',
                                'Which fish would survive in salt water?']})

df
```

I am trying to find Cosine similarity score between each pair of sentences of q1 and q2 columns iteratively (map or apply functions using list comprehension) (create a new column  cos_sim_q1q2.

Iterative apply the below steps across each rows of df:

Apply preprocessing function on q1 and q2 columns

```
def preprocessing(text):
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    tokens = [w for w in words if w.lower() not in string.punctuation]
    stopw = stopwords.words('english')
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stopw]
    preprocessed_text = ' '.join(tokens)
    return preprocessed_text
```

Then vectorize the texts

```
import string
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
doc_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(.....)
```

Then calculate the cosine similarity between each text pairs

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

cosine_similarity(vectorized(df['q1'][0]), vectorized(df['q2'][0]).....) and save the similarity score in a new column say cos_sim_q1q2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def preprocessing(text):
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    tokens = [w for w in words if w.lower() not in string.punctuation]
    stopw = stopwords.words('english')
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stopw]
    preprocessed_text = ' '.join(tokens)
    return preprocessed_text 

data_sim['question1'] = data_sim['question1'].apply(preprocessing)
data_sim['question2'] = data_sim['question2'].apply(preprocessing)
```

###### TFIDF(Cosine distance)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer("content", lowercase=True, analyzer="word", use_idf=True)

def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
    # text1 = 'what is the story of kohinoor kohinoor diamond'
    # text2 = 'what would happen if the indian government stole the kohinoor kohinoor diamond back'
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    #   print (tfidf)

cos_sim=[]
for text1,text2 in zip(df['q1'],data_sim['q2']):
    cos_sim_value=cosine_sim(text1,text2)
    cos_sim.append(cos_sim_value)
        return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]

cos_sim
```